# How Can I find the Differential of a Function of Matrices?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

**Question**

Write $(2n\times 2n)$-matrices in block form

$A=$

$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$
$\in Mat_{\mathbb{R}}(2n)$

where each of $a,b,c,d$ is an $n\times n$ block. Define

$J=$

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$

where 1 is a shorthand for an $n\times n$ identity matrix. Let

$Sp(2n)= \{ A\in Mat_\mathbb{R}(2n)| AJA^T=J \}$,

so that $Sp(2n)=F^{-1}J$, where $F: Mat_{\mathbb{R}}(2n)\rightarrow Skew_{\mathbb{R}}(2n)$ is the map $F(A)=AJA^T$. Here, the codomain is the set of real $n\times n$ matrices satisfying $C=-C^T$.

Find the differential $D_AF: Mat_{\mathbb{R}}(2n)\rightarrow Skew_{\mathbb{R}}(2n)$

**Note**
I can find the differential of a function. However, I can’t seem to handle this, probably because it involves matrices. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **HINT**: Calculate the directional derivative $D_AF(B)$ as a limit.

Comment: @TedShifrin $D_AF(B) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{F(A+tB)-F(A)}{t}$. If we expand this to the first order in t and ignore $O(t^2)$, we will have $AJB^T+BJA^T$. To ensure $D_AF(B)$ is skew-symmetric, we will have $D_AF(B)=\frac{D_AF(B)-(D_AF(B))^T}{2}$. And using the fact that $J$ is skew symmetric, we will get $AJB^T+BJA^T$ as we would expect. Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: You should realize that $AJB^\top + BJA^\top$ is automatically skew-symmetric before you start. But yes, this is fine.

Comment: @MrProf You should write an answer to your own question.